# How can I get BibTeX to show months in another language than English?

Tags: latex, localization, bibtex

I'm using three-letter abbreviations in BibTex for the months, but when I compile my document, the month-names come out in English.

Can I somehow change the output language?

I'm using `natbib`, but don't mind switching back to vanilla BibTeX if that's required.

Comment: you might get a better answer on stackoverflow, as latex questions are considered programming over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the output language of the three-letter month abbreviations is controlled by the bibliography style.  See, for example, these [French bibliography styles](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/bib-fr/).

Comment: It is.  This is one of these few adjustments that is easy to make to a .bst program.